# Drop Down Menu Update Selection In Database

Tags: drop-down-menu, kohana

I don't know how to save a change from a drop down menu to a database.

I grab the list from a database.

```
$list_categories = ORM::factory('category')->find_all()->as_array('category_id','category_name');
```

I grab the selected category that is already saved in the database.

```
$selected_category = $edit_forum->category_id;
```

I echo the drop down menu.

```
Form::select('category', $list_categories, $selected_category);
```

Let's say it lists A, B, C. B is the current selected category and I want to change it to A. I want to save this change to the database, but don't know how.

I currently do the following to save to the database:

```
    $edit_forum->values($this->request->post());

    $errors = array();

    try {

        $edit_forum->save();

        $this->request->redirect('acp/forums');

   } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $ex) {

       $errors = $ex->errors('validation');

   }
```

The above works fine with text fields, but not the drop down menu.

Edit: My problem seems to be that I can't change the category_id. Anyone know how? category_id is a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My routes, rules, and labels were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$edit_forum = new Model_Category($this->request->param('id'));

    if ( ! $edit_forum->loaded())
        throw new HTTP_Exception_404("Category not found");

    if ($this->request->post())
    {
        try
        {
            $edit_forum->values($this->request->post())
                ->update();

            //if you want to make redirection somewhere after update
            //$this->redirect('');  

        }
        catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
        {
            $this->view->errors = $e->errors('');
        }
    }
```

If I'm getting right what you want. Hope this help.

```
 <select id="category" name="category_id">
     <option value="category_id">category_name</option>
 </select>
```